# Get JSON data from http with Swift2

Tags: json, http, swift2

I'm new at Swift2 and need some help to list JSON data from a website (http://192.168.0.60:6002/api/tag/string/list?format=json)

The site return this:

```
{
”OUTSIDE RH":"74",
"WEATHER::TODAYWINDDIRECTION":"North-northwest",
"SONOS::RADIO":"8",
"WEATHER::TODAYTEMP":"17",
"WEATHER::DAYAFTERTOMORROWTEMP":"20",
"1-WIRE::MOISTUREMETER::RAWVALUE1":"925",
"STATUS::TRAGARD":"True",
"TEMPERATUR::GARAGE":"25",
"WEATHER::TOMORROW":"Cloudy",
"GARAGERH":"63",
"POOLTEMP":"13.1",
"WEATHER::DAYAFTERTOMORROWWINDDIRECTION":"West-northwest",
"1-WIRE::MOISTUREMETER::RAWVALUE3":"68"
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but here's some crazy advice: To get answers instead of down votes on StackOverflow, you should explain very specifically what you have tried, and which detail didn't work the way you expected. You shouldn't give the impression, that you did not bother to read any swift tutorial first or at least do a Google search on 'swift json'. Do your homework and when you're really stuck, you'll find help here. :)

Comment: Sorry if I gave that impression. Of course I have read lots of Swift2 guides and googled a lot on swift2 json. But I can't real get it. That's way I need help from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can use Alamofire. It allows you to deal with HTTP requests such a GET and POST.

Download it using Cocoapods, here's a link to it's GitHub page: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

After that, import it at the top of your class.

Then wherever you want to get the JSON, call this method:

```
func requestJSON(){
        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://192.168.0.60:6002/api/tag/string/list?format=json)").responseJSON { (response) in
              if let jsonDictionary = response.result.value{
                   print(jsonDictionary)
        }
}
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

Step one: follow a tutorial - even if it's using Swift 1.2 - like this one: [Working with JSON in Swift Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/82706/working-with-json-in-swift-tutorial)

Step two: update your code to Swift 2 if necessary. Use resources like [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html), watch WWDC 2015 videos like [Whats new in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=106) and maybe take a look at third party stuff like ["What's new in Swift 2" (Ray Wenderlich)](http://www.raywenderlich.com/108522/whats-new-in-swift-2).

That should get you pretty far. If you're still really stuck somewhere:

Step three: Ask a new, specific question on StackOverflow. :)